# Select distinct values of distinct group

Tags: php, mysql, performance, multidimensional-array, distinct

I have a table similar to this:

```
    id  title  year
    ---------------
    1    abc   1999
    2    abc   2000
    3    abc   2000
    4    abc   1998
    5    bce   1999
    6    bce   1999
    7    def   1999
    8    def   1999
    9    def   2000
```

I am trying to get an array similar to

```
array('abc' => 'array(1999,2000,1998)', 'bce' => 'array(1999)', 'def' => 'array(1999, 2000)');
```

I know a long way and I assume its time consuming way:

```
PHP:
$rid = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT title from table_name ORDER BY ASC);
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
   $title = $arr
   $rid = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT title from table_name ORDER BY ASC);
   $yearArr = array();
   while($arr2 = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
      $yearArr[] = $arr2['year'];
   }
   $finalArr = array(title => $yearArr);
}
```

Finally I am getting the array I was looking for, but from the above code if I have 1000 distinct titles then the whole process will execute 1001 queries. Is there any short way of doing this?

I also found one similar one but, I could not go further:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year,title FROM table_name WHERE title IN (SELECT DISTINCT title FROM papers_scanned_01) ORDER BY title ASC, year DESC
```

using the above query I am getting an array as below

```
array( [0] => 'abc', [1] => '1999', [2] => '2000', [3] => '1998', [4] => 'bce' and so on..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get your desired array with only 1 SQL executed

```
$sql = "SELECT title, group_concat(year) as years FROM table_name group by title"
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
   $arr[$row['title']] = explode(',',$row['years']);
}
```

Comment: Wow that was awesome.. I guess I was searching with wrong keyword on google. thanks a lot man..

Comment: Side note The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat   so you can lose data

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword in `group_concat()` function to fetch distinct values.

Modify your query like this -

```
SELECT title, group_concat(DISTINCT year) as years
FROM tb1
group by title
```

Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0812a/4

**Output** -

```
TITLE   YEARS
abc     1999,2000,1998
bce     1999
def     1999,2000
```